# The sink operator waits for response from database in Flink?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, apache-flink

I am wondering that the detail procedure of the sink when Flink inserts the records to database in streaming.

My configuration is that I use the checkpoint with 5 minutes using exactly once.

My understanding is that when the message is coming from the upstream operator, the sink operator tries to insert the records to connected external system such as Kafka or database before checkpoint barrier. Then checkpoint barrier arrives at the sink operator, then it tries to snapshot its state and sends ack message to job manager to notify completion of the checkpoint.

Above scenario, I use the dynamoDB for the sink and ran the flink app during one week and saw that all the checkpoint is completed successfully in the dashboard.

**First question.**

In this scenario, can data loss be happened in the sink operator for various reasons?
I know that completion of checkpoint means that it is successfully committed the records from source to sink before next checkpoint. So whatever the databases I use or whatever the mechanism I use for sink such as async sink or one phase commit sink, it is guaranteed that the data loss won't be happened.

**Second question.**

Also when the checkpoint failed, the data loss won't be happened because the job restarts from the successful checkpoint offset.

**Third question**

At sink operator, the sink operator waits until the database successfully insert the data into its system? When I use the dynamodb, the sink operator waits until dynamodb process the in flight data and responses from database? Or the sink operator just passes the data into dynamodb and it does not care whether dynamodb's db processing including its response? It means that the sink does not wait for response from database.

I hope you understand for my clarity.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe [this blog post from the Flink project blog](https://flink.apache.org/2018/02/28/an-overview-of-end-to-end-exactly-once-processing-in-apache-flink-with-apache-kafka-too/) answers your questions, at least in general. I'm not sure how the dynamo db sink is implemented.